# Oddities in fail2ban regex

Tags: fail2ban

*This appears to be a bug in fail2ban, with different behaviour between the fail2ban-regex tool and a failregex filter*

I am attempting to develop a new regex rule for fail2ban, to match:

`\"%20and%20\"x\"%3D\"x`

When using fail2ban-regex, this appears to produce the desired result:

`^<HOST>.*GET.*\\"%20and%20\\"x\\"%3D\\"x.* 200.*$`

As does this:

`^<HOST>.*GET.*\\\"%20and%20\\\"x\\\"%3D\\\"x.* 200.*$`

However, when I put either of these into a filter, I get the following error:

`Failed during configuration: '%' must be followed by '%' or '(', found:…`

To have this work in a filter you have to double-up the ‘%’, ie ‘%%’:

`^<HOST>.*GET.*\\\"%%20and%%20\\\"x\\\"%%3D\\\"x.* 200.*$`

While this gets the required hits running as a filter, it gets none running through fail2ban-regex.

I tried the `\\\\` as Andre suggested below, but this gets no results in fail2ban-regex.

So, as this appears to be differential behaviour, I am going to file it as a bug.

Comment: %% worked out for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to Python's own site a singe backslash `"\"` has to be written as `"\\\\"` and there's no mention of `%`.

> Regular expressions use the backslash character ('') to indicate
> special forms or to allow special characters to be used without
> invoking their special meaning. This collides with Python’s usage of
> the same character for the same purpose in string literals; for
> example, to match a literal backslash, one might have to write '\\'
> as the pattern string, because the regular expression must be \, and
> each backslash must be expressed as \ inside a regular Python string
> literal

I would just go with:

```
failregex = (?i)^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST|HEAD|PUT).*20and.*3d.*$
```

the `.*` wil match anything inbetween anyways and `(?i)` makes the entire regex case-insensitive